# __RequestVerificationToken cookie not saved and sent in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

using MVC4;

In IE 10 and FF (current), the __RequestVerificationToken cookie is received in the response and sent in the next request.

In Chrome, the __RequestVerificationToken cookie is received in the response but not sent in the next request.

I am not using ajax, just a standard form post. In Chrome dev tools, I see the cookie in the response but the cookie is not present in the 'Resources > Cookies' section.

Renaming the cooking to 'Test' works and Chrome sees it in the response, stores it and sends in the next request, but why isn't the default name working?

Comment: Did you ever find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I just had this problem.

I was using the `Edit This Cookie` Chrome extension and had used it to manually clear the cookies.

*No matter what* I tried (reboot/`Session.Abandon();`/anything) Chrome wouldn't send the `__RequestValidationToken` cookie any more.

I disabled (not uninstalled) the `Edit This Cookie` extension, tried again, it all worked. Then I re-enabled the extension and everything remained fine.

So I guess it's some kind of quirky bug in how that extension works. It might also affect other cookie editing extensions, but I haven't tested this.